# WSGI - Attribute no 'user' Error

Tags: python, django, iis-7.5, wsgi

Hello i'm trying to run some python/django in a windows iis 7.5 environment. After starting the server (localhost:8888) I receive the following error. This error is generated only after accessing localhost:8888.

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\
 base.py", line 224, in handle_uncaught_exception
   return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5-py2.7.egg\django\utils\decorato
  rs.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ecm-2.1.2-py2.7.egg\ecm\views\custom_handl
  ers.py", line 22, in server_error
      http.HttpResponseServerError(t.render(RequestContext(request)))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5-py2.7.egg\django\template\conte
   xt.py", line 179, in __init__
   self.update(processor(request))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ecm-2.1.2-py2.7.egg\ecm\views\context_proc
   essors.py", line 55, in menu
    if request.user.is_superuser or UrlPermission.user_has_access(request.user,
   menu['url']):
  AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
   <WSGIServer fileno=552 address=127.0.0.1:8888>: Failed to handle request:
    request = GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 from ('127.0.0.1', 50325)
   application = <django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x022CDCB0>
```

I've looked around and trie dmany of the proposed solutions - my middleware in django looks like this.

```
 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (

   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
   # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  )
```

Here is the code which references the request.user line.

```
def menu(request):
"""
Adds the variable {{ user_menu }} to all the templates.

The menu is composed with items from each ECM app/plugin (see the menu.py files)
The items are dynamically displayed according to user accesses.
"""
user_menus = []
for menu in ECM_MENUS:
    if request.user.is_superuser or UrlPermission.user_has_access(request.user,        menu['url']):
        user_menus.append(menu)
data = {
    'menus': user_menus, 
    'path': str(request.get_full_path())
}
return {'user_menu': render_to_string('ecm/menu.html', data), 'request_path':        data['path']}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your middleware, although I am no django expert. Can you post the code where you are referencing `user`?

Comment: Just a big guess since I'm not familiar with where the `user` comes from but maybe Authentication and Session middlewares need to be re-ordered

Comment: @johnthexiii - from the traceback, the error is raised by the "ecm" package (googled it: "EVE Corp Management is a management and decision-making helper-application for EVE Online."). Haven't heard of it before...

Comment: Code that references the request.user is posted. I have a feeling it's got something to do with the WGSI & windows stuff and not the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too.
Set Debug to True in settings.ini.